# No value given for one or more required parameters - Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
sql1 = "SELECT distinct(Area) FROM (" + tablename + ")"
        Dim ds_area As New DataSet
        Dim da_area As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, MyConnection)
        da_area.Fill(ds_area)
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = ds_area.Tables(0)
        Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Area"
        Me.ListBox1.ValueMember = "Area"
        Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Me.cmbArea.Items.Insert(0, "Select All")
        For i = 0 To ds_area.Tables(0).Rows.Count() - 1
            Me.cmbArea.Items.Add(ds_area.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString)
        Next
        Me.cmbArea.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The error report shows "No value given for one or mor required parameters"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the parentheses around `tablename`.  Also, does `tablename` have a valid value?  Have you tried stepping through the code to see which line is throwing the error?

Comment: The code working with the file columns which have characters , now i need it for numerics

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is correctly.

I have caught the same error as yours

At that time , it cannt found the column name (Area)

Comment: I didn't enclose the excel file . The column Area resides on the excel file .